# Can I add metadata to a jpeg in Android?

Tags: photos

Does anyone know of a way to take `jpeg`s imported from my camera onto my Android tablet then add the metadata properties that Windows calls Title, Tags (I assume, possibly wrong, that this is Keywords in `EXIF` terms) and possibly Subject so that they are there when I eventually transfer the photos to  Windows PC?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are several exif editors in Google Play. One of them is [EXIF Tag Editor (Photo)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teapps.exiftageditor).

As suggested by Izzy, there are also gallery apps that can do this:

- [JustPictures!](http://www.appbrain.com/app/JustPictures/com.justpictures)
- [Photo Mate](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Photo-Mate/com.tsgames.pictureinfo)

Note that the latter two apps are no longer available on Play Store.